# Unable to assign the ENV value dynamically using Docker and Angular

Tags: angular, docker

I need to pass the `env` value in docker run command and get that value in Angular application. But as per my current docker structure its not working as expected. I am explaining my code below.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:12-alpine as angular-build
#FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine

RUN echo "NODE Version:" && node --version
RUN echo "NPM Version:" && npm --version

COPY ./app /app

WORKDIR /app/mean-stack/angular-js
RUN npm install
#COPY . /app/mean-stack/angular-js
RUN npm run build --prod





FROM node:10.22.1-alpine3.9



ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools


RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache openssl-dev libffi-dev gcc musl-dev python3-dev make


RUN pip install flask requests rstr robotframework natsort
RUN pip install paramiko dpath zipfile36 simplejson
RUN pip install jsonpickle


RUN echo "NODE Version:" && node --version
RUN echo "NPM Version:" && npm --version


COPY install-nginx-alpine.sh /

RUN sh /install-nginx-alpine.sh

EXPOSE 90

# # Expose 443, in case of LTS / HTTPS
EXPOSE 443

# Install uWSGI
RUN apk add --no-cache uwsgi-python3

# Copy the base uWSGI ini file to enable default dynamic uwsgi process number
COPY uwsgi.ini /etc/uwsgi/

# Install Supervisord
RUN apk add --no-cache supervisor
# Custom Supervisord config
COPY supervisord-alpine.ini /etc/supervisor.d/supervisord.ini

# uWSGI Python plugin
# As an env var to re-use the config file
ENV UWSGI_PLUGIN python3

# Which uWSGI .ini file should be used, to make it customizable
ENV UWSGI_INI /app/uwsgi.ini

# By default, run 2 processes
ENV UWSGI_CHEAPER 2

# By default, when on demand, run up to 16 processes
ENV UWSGI_PROCESSES 16

# By default, allow unlimited file sizes, modify it to limit the file sizes
# To have a maximum of 1 MB (Nginx's default) change the line to:
# ENV NGINX_MAX_UPLOAD 1m
ENV NGINX_MAX_UPLOAD 0

# By default, Nginx will run a single worker process, setting it to auto
# will create a worker for each CPU core
ENV NGINX_WORKER_PROCESSES 1

# By default, Nginx listens on port 80.
# To modify this, change LISTEN_PORT environment variable.
# (in a Dockerfile or with an option for `docker run`)
ENV LISTEN_PORT 90

# Used by the entrypoint to explicitly add installed Python packages
# and uWSGI Python packages to PYTHONPATH otherwise uWSGI can't import Flask
ENV ALPINEPYTHON python3.8

# Copy start.sh script that will check for a /app/prestart.sh script and run it before starting the app
COPY start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh



RUN echo "uwsgi_read_timeout 7200s;" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/custom_timeout.conf


# URL under which static (not modified by Python) files will be requested
# They will be served by Nginx directly, without being handled by uWSGI
ENV STATIC_URL /site
# Absolute path in where the static files wil be
ENV STATIC_PATH /app/static/angular

# If STATIC_INDEX is 1, serve / with /static/index.html directly (or the static URL configured)
# ENV STATIC_INDEX 1
ENV STATIC_INDEX 0

# Add demo app
COPY ./app /app


WORKDIR /app/mean-stack/node-js
RUN echo "$WORKDIR"
RUN pwd
RUN ls -lt
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8081


# Angular resources
#WORKDIR /app/mean-stack/angular-js
#RUN npm install
#COPY . /app/mean-stack/angular-js
#RUN npm run build --prod

RUN mkdir /app/static/angular
COPY --from=angular-build /app/mean-stack/angular-js/dist/ubot /app/static/angular

# When the container starts, replace the env.js with values from environment variables
#CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /app/static/angular/assets/env.template.js > /app/static/angular/assets/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]

## Remove default nginx index page
#RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
#
## Copy from the stahg 1
#COPY --from=angular-build /app/mean-stack/angular-js/dist/ubot /usr/share/nginx/html

#EXPOSE 4200 90

#WORKDIR /user/share/n
WORKDIR /app


# Make /app/* available to be imported by Python globally to better support several use cases like Alembic migrations.
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app
ENV FLASK_DEBUG=1

# Move the base entrypoint to reuse it
COPY uwsgi-nginx-entrypoint.sh /uwsgi-nginx-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /uwsgi-nginx-entrypoint.sh

# Copy the entrypoint that will generate Nginx additional configs
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

#Install mongodb
RUN cp /etc/apk/repositories /etc/apk/repositories_bak
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main' > /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community' >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update &&  apk --no-cache --update add mongodb
RUN mongo --version
RUN mkdir -p /data/db
EXPOSE 27017


ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

# Run the start script provided by the parent image tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx.
# It will check for an /app/prestart.sh script (e.g. for migrations)
# And then will start Supervisor, which in turn will start Nginx and uWSGI
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

**start.sh:**

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
set -e

# If there's a prestart.sh script in the /app directory, run it before starting
PRE_START_PATH=/app/prestart.sh
echo "Checking for script in $PRE_START_PATH"
if [ -f $PRE_START_PATH ] ; then
    echo "Running script $PRE_START_PATH"
    . $PRE_START_PATH
else
    echo "There is no script $PRE_START_PATH"
fi

# Start Supervisor, with Nginx and uWSGI
#exec /usr/bin/supervisord
/usr/sbin/nginx &
/usr/sbin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini &
node mean-stack/node-js/app.js &
mongod &
/bin/ash
tail -f /dev/null

echo "NODE_PORT = ${NODE_PORT}"
envsubst < "/app/static/angular/assets/env.template.js" > "/app/static/angular/assets/env.js"
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

In this `start.sh` file I have set the `NODE_PORT` and replacing `env.js` file with `env.template.js`. I am also explaining below.

**assets/env.js**

```
(function(window) {
    window["env"] = window["env"] || {};

    // Environment variables
    window["env"]["nodePort"] = 1900;
    console.log('env port', window["env"]["nodePort"]);
})(this);
```

**assets/env.template.js**

```
(function(window) {
    window.env = window.env || {};
    console.log('template', "${NODE_PORT}");
    // Environment variables
    window["env"]["nodePort"] = "${NODE_PORT}";
})(this);
```

I have included `env.js` into index.html.

```
sudo docker run -d -it -p 8999:90 -p 1905:8081 --env NODE_PORT=1905 --name test-container-ubot  ubot-container:lates
```

So I need when the above command will run then I should get that `NODE_PORT=1905` inside angular file. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only code that might play with env is this code which may change the $NODE_PORT ( if defined ) ..
Try to comment this
if [ -f $PRE_START_PATH ] ; then
echo "Running script $PRE_START_PATH"

TRY TO COMMENT THIS LINE AND CHECK

### #  . $PRE_START_PATH

else
echo "There is no script $PRE_START_PATH"
fi

and check.

Comment: Can you please post your answer because its bit confusing. Also I have `prestart.sh` inside app directory.

Comment: what is the content of prestart.sh ?

Comment: only comment lines. `echo "Running inside /app/prestart.sh, you could add migrations to this file, e.g.:"

echo "
#! /usr/bin/env bash
# Let the DB start
sleep 10;
# Run migrations
alembic upgrade head
"`

Comment: I comment and check as per you but still unable to fetch the env values.

Comment: In: start.sh there is and echo statement just before "envsubst" command. what is the output there ? Is it showing 1905 ? If not then put the echo statement at the begining of the start.sh script.. it should display 1905 . If still you cant get it means the docker command needs to caliberated